# How do I disable dual screen after connect HDMI cable?

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, hdmi

I plugged the HDMI connector and turned on the computer, but when the log in screen appears the laptop screen appears split in 2, one top and one bottom. The external monitor connected via HDMI works fine. I just need to know how do I disable dual screen from laptop and back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use the external monitor. But regardless, all you have to do is go into Display, select the monitor you want to turn off, & turn it off using the slider below the display image.

Comment: I want to use both, but my laptop shows 2 screens, it's split in the middle. I want full screen in the laptop like it is in the external monitor.

Comment: Checking the  mirror option in the monitor settings with make the two monitors identical.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/539321/722892) answer. Does this help you? It says:

> I plugged the HDMI cable in (caused screen split) then took it out and
>   closed the lid. When I opened the laptop and logged back in it allowed
>   me to connect the second monitor.