# Ubuntu 14.04 - HDMI connection causes horizontal split

Tags: multiple-monitors, radeon, hdmi, gallium

Running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Edge 535 laptop. When I connect my HDMI cable in order to connect the laptop to the TV the screen splits horizontally and the OS becomes unresponsive.

Screenshot:

[image]

Am I missing something in connecting my laptop to an external monitor?

```
Memory 3.2GiB
Processor AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics x 4
Graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA
OS Type 64-bit
Disk 602.1 GB
```

Comment: Have you installed any type of drivers or you are running the default ones?

Comment: Still using the default driver.

Comment: Installed the ATI driver which worked in displaying a second monitor. However it caused screen resolution issues when unplugged and did not allow me to play audio trough the TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working.

I plugged the HDMI cable in (caused screen split) then took it out and closed the lid. When I opened the laptop and logged back in it allowed me to connect the second monitor.